# About listing bash options on `set`

Tags: bash, set

When we print the console settings with the `echo $-` command, we output `himBHs` by default. However, when we run the same command in any script file, we only output `hB`.

```
root@root:~# echo $-
himBHs
root@root:~# ./abc.sh 
hB
root@root:~#
```

What I'm wondering is, even though we're running the script from a `/bin/bash` environment, why don't the same default settings apply ?

For example, when I start a new sub-shell process with the command `/bin/bash` **on the console** and list the settings, I get output `himBHs`.

```
root@root:~# /bin/bash
root@root:~# echo $-
himBHs
```

When I try to perform the same process from within the **shell file**, the output I get is "**hB**".

```
root@root:~# ./abc.sh 
hB
```

I've tried the same process with shebang and without the shebang, but my script file is either `bash script_file` or `./script_file` if I run, it gives the same result(`hB`).

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you run a script, the parent shell (the one you run your commands from) starts a non-interactive shell to run your script which has interactive flag disabled `i` and only turns on two options

- `-h` to locate and remember (hash) commands as they are looked up for execution.
- `-B` to allow the shell to perform brace expansion

You can see the complete list of `set` options which will be seen in the output of `$-` - [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Other options available in the interactive shell, `-i` to indicate to run the shell in interactive mode

- `-m` to allow Job control
- `-H` to enable `!` style history substitution

Comment: Thank you your answer. Another issue I'm curious about is that we can assign ambient features with shebang. For example `#!with /bin / bash-euxo`, we can determine the properties of the environment in which the script file will be executed. However, the same operation'#!when we try `/usr/bin / env bash-euxo`, we get an error. Why?

Comment: @testter: Yes, instead of adding duplicate information, you can look at these following posts [Multiple arguments in shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399690/112235), [Shebang line with `#!/usr/bin/env command --argument` fails on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63979/112235) and [How to pass arguments to the shebang interpreter when executing a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182227/112235)

Answer (score 4):

Several settings are enabled (or disabled) by default depending on whether the Bash is being run interactively, in POSIX mode, or other things. For example, from the output of `help set`:

```
  -H  Enable ! style history substitution.  This flag is on
      by default when the shell is interactive.
```

Or:

```
  -p  Turned on whenever the real and effective user ids do not match.
```

It just happens that for an interactive, non-POSIX-mode Bash, the options enabled are `himBHs` (`-i` is for interactive mode, `-s` is for reading in commands from standard input, the other options are listed in `help set`).

Comment: QuickQ: Why doesn't the GNU bash manual explain about the `-s` flag explicitly? or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Inian it's mentioned in [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash). If you're asking why it being listed in `$-` isn't explained, that's probably an oversight. It's only necessary to use it explicitiy for interactive shells if you have a non-option argument.

Comment: You are wrong for `-p`. It needs to be set from outside to prevent the shell from resetting the effective uid/gid.